# How to create a numpy record array?

Tags: python, numpy

This gives me an error:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 'O', 1]],
             dtype=np.dtype([('step', 'int32'),
                             ('symbol', '|S1'),
                             ('index', 'int32')]))

TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

I don't know why this should fail?

Alternatlively, how can I force something like this statement to work?

```
x = np.array([[1, 'O', 1]])
```

then

```
x.dtype = np.dtype([('step', 'int32'),('symbol', '|S1'),('index', 'int32')])
```

or

```
x.view(dtype=np.dtype([('step', 'int32'),('symbol', '|S1'),('index', 'int32')]))
```

both give me

```
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

**Edit**

If I try to enter each record as a tuple, it will think that the triple is a single value, rather than three separate fields? For instance:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([(1, 'O', 1)],
             dtype=np.dtype([('step', 'int32'),
                             ('symbol', '|S1'),
                             ('index', 'int32')]))
```

seems fine until I do this:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rec
rec.append_fields(x,'x',x['index']+1)
```

gives me

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

presumably because `x.shape` is (1,) rather than (1,3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make each row a tuple, not a list:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([(1, 'O', 1)],
             dtype=np.dtype([('step', 'int32'),
                             ('symbol', '|S1'),
                             ('index', 'int32')]))
```

Numpy developer [Robert Kern explains](http://web.archive.org/web/20130617020606/http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-September/058390.html):

> As a rule, tuples are considered "scalar" records and lists are
>   recursed upon. This rule helps numpy.array() figure out which
>   sequences are records and which are other sequences to be recursed
>   upon; i.e. which sequences create another dimension and which are the
>   atomic elements.

Comment: Thanks, but then the shape of x is (1,) rather than (1,3)?

Comment: That's what you are supposed to get when defining a structured array. You can access the columns with syntax like: `x['symbol']`

Comment: Thanks I'll post the appending field as a separate question.

Comment: The link seems to broken: http://web.archive.org/web/20130617020606/http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-September/058390.html

Answer (score 2):

I will show a more general way of creating record array:

```
# prepare the array with different types
recarr = np.zeros((4,), dtype=('i4,f4,a10'))

# creating the columns
col1 = [1, 7, 2, 3]
col2 = [1.1, 0.5, 2, 7.45]
col3 = ['This', 'is', 'text', '!!!']

# create a list of tuples from columns
# prepare = zip(col1, col2, col3)  # Python 2

prepare = list(zip(col1, col2, col3))  # Python 3

# assigning value so recarr
recarr[:] = prepare
```

Now you can assign names for each of the columns:

```
recarr.dtype.names = ('ID' , 'price', 'text')
```

and later get the values for this column:

```
print recarr('price')
```